# Is bluray capable of multisession?

Tags: disk-image, burning, blu-ray, k3b

Is Bluray disk capable of multisession writing, in principle? I checked the forums and all major disk burning applications that are supported on Ubuntu do not work with multisession blurays. Could it be that Bluray standard does not support multisessions at all? Nada?

Alternatively: would it be possible to, for example, burn one huge zeroed file and then modify it after the fact? Or use UDF packet writing mode?

Comment: You would need to use BD-RE disks

Comment: Thank you. Now that I think of I might as well use DVD-RW instead.